# table() on my data is giving counts off-by-one

Tags: r, count

in R, if I have a data-structure my_data like:

```
participant var score
`
1           a   ... 
            b   ...
            c   ...
            a   ...
2           b   ...
            a   ...
            c   ...
            c   ...
3           b   ...
            c   ...
            a   ...
            b   ...
```

and I write the function to count the frequencies of var, through table(my_data$participant, my_data$var), the result is:

```
   a  b  c
1  1  0  0
2  0  1  0
3  0  1  0
```

while it should be

```
   a  b  c
1  2  1  1
2  1  1  2
3  1  2  1
```

This happens for the reason that the function selects only those lines in which 'participant' is not empty. 
Is there a default way to tell the software to associate to the same participant those empty lines?

Comment: Please post reproducible code and data. Otherwise noone can help. table() has always worked fine, IME. Check if some entries are `NA`, and if they are, use `table(..., useNA='ifany'...)`

Comment: Fill in the empty values. Use `zoo::na.locf` or similar to replace blanks with the last observation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `na.locf` from the zoo package:

```
# sample data
my_data = data.frame(participant=c("1","","","2","",""),var = c("a","a","b","a","a","c"),stringsAsFactors = F)

library(zoo)
# first, replace empty elements with NA, then use na.locf
my_data$participant[nchar(my_data$participant)==0]=NA
my_data$participant = na.locf(my_data$participant)
table(my_data$participant, my_data$var)
```

Output:

```
    a b c
  1 2 1 0
  2 2 0 1
```

Hope this helps!